# Jquery how to check checkbox on div click, change class and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to checkbox when the div.menuitem is clicked and then it should change class and show the content in the div with **class** of hidediv. When the div.menuitem is again clicked it should remove the class and hide the div again and uncheck the checkbox.

Want I want to do:

1. Only show the content of the hidediv when the menuitem is pressed. (checkbox should be checked)
2. When the menuitem is pressed the checkbox should be checked
3. When the menuitem is clicked again the hidediv should be hidden again. (checkbox unchecked)
4. And the checkbox should be uncheched

Illustration of my menu form:

```
<div class="menuitem">
1.Company1
</div>
<div class="hidediv">
1.1 Company 1.1 
1.2 Company 1.2
</div>

<div class="menuitem">
1.Company2
</div>
<div class="hidediv">
1.1 Company 2.1 
1.2 Company 2.2
</div>
```

My previous Jquery code, which only is trigger when the checkbox is clicked. I want pretty 
similar function to this, the checkbox should also be trigghed when the div is clicked:

```
$('.menuitem input:checkbox').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('div.hidediv').addClass('someclass').show(200); // not needed it there is another way of identifying the div later to add to hidediv class again.
            $('div.hidediv').removeClass('hidediv');
        } else {
            $('div.someclass').addClass('hidediv').hide(200); 
        }
});
});
```

My Jquery so far(not working):

```
$('.menuitem').click(function(e){
$(this).addClass('menuclicked');          
$('div.hidediv').addClass('clicked').show(200);
            $('div.hidediv').removeClass('hidediv');
        } else {
            $('div.someclass').addClass('hidediv').hide(200); 
        }
$('.menuclicked').click(function(e){
$('div.someclass').addClass('hidediv').hide(200); 
});
```

My HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

        <div class="menuitem">
        <label for="search_company1">company1</label>

        <input name="search[company1_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="search_company1_is_true" name="search[company1_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="menuitem">
        <label for="search_company3">company3</label>
        <input name="search[company3_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="search_company3_is_true" name="search[company3_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        </div>
 <div class="hidediv">
        <div class="menuitem">
        <label for="search_company2">company2</label>
        <input name="search[company2_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="search_company2_is_true" name="search[company2_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <div>
</div>
    <input id="search_submit" name="commit" style="display:none;" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The "Jquery so far" as posted is invalid - unbalanced braces, an `else` with no `if` ... the close-brace on the fifth line right before the else matches to the open-brace of the function itself.

Comment: You have **two** visible checkboxes, and **one** hidden. Which of the two visible checkboxes should show the hidden checkbox?

Comment: The parent of the hidden checkbox

Comment: Your edit clarifies things a little, but it's still ambiguous as to which of the visibile checkboxes should cause the hidden checkbox to appear/disappear. As to your comment: none of the checkboxes are parents of another. They're all within the same `form`, but that doesn't really clarify anything.

Comment: Example if the visable checkbox number 2 is clicked it should be the hidediv number 2 (the child to the visable checkbox)

Comment: Yeah, you don't have any parent/children checkboxes in your html, just siblings.

Comment: Is it not possiable to only select hidediv number 2 if visable checkbox number 2 is clicked

Comment: Can I ***strongly*** suggest that you organise, or re-organise, your (x)html so that the structure clearly clarifies your intent. I can't connect what you're saying with the code you've posted. And I [don't think I'm the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919274/jquery-how-to-check-checkbox-on-div-click-change-class-and-show-div/6919395#6919395).

Comment: How should I organize it? Should I create CSS classes for each div that got hidden checkboxes? To select the hidden checkboxes? .menuitem1 .hidediv, menuitem2 hidediv....

Comment: And then repeated Jquery code to create the hide/show div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help. I think you are structuring this wrong. You have three fields in your html, with the third being hidden. I assume when you fill in the first one you want nothing to happen, but clicking the second one should show the third field?

Try this:

```
//Use toggle instead of .click()
$('.menuitem').toggle(function(){
    $('div.hidediv').addClass('clicked').show(200);
}, function(){
    $('div.hidediv').removeClass('clicked').hide(200);
});
```

This will effect all divs with the "menuitem" class, meaning when you click on any of the three it will toggle showing/hiding the div with the "hidediv" class.

*edit* you have a couple valid answers here, but I think you're approaching this wrong. If you go try the jsfiddle posted by another user, whos' javascript does the same as mine - it reveals the problem I talked about above. You cannot select all three boxes without some clever clicking. Each click will toggle showing/hiding the third check box. Might I suggest modifying your code like so:

```
//Use toggle instead of .click()
$('.toggleMenuItem').toggle(function(){
    $('div.hidediv').addClass('clicked').show(200);
}, function(){
    $('div.hidediv').removeClass('clicked').hide(200);
});

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" method="get">

    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    </div>

        <div class="menuitem">
            <label for="search_company1">company1</label>
        <input name="search[company1_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <input id="search_company1_is_true" name="search[company1_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        </div>

        <div class="menuitem toggleMenuItem">
            <label for="search_company3">company3</label>
            <input name="search[company3_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <input id="search_company3_is_true" name="search[company3_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        </div>

    <div class="hidediv">
            <div class="menuitem">
                <label for="search_company2">company2</label>
                <input name="search[company2_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input id="search_company2_is_true" name="search[company2_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <div>
    </div>
        <input id="search_submit" name="commit" style="display:none;" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This will make it so only clicking the checkboxes with the class ".toggleMenuItem" will show the third checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$('.menuitem').click(function(e){
if($(this).hasClass('menuClicked')){
    // Already clicked
    $(this)
        .removeClass('menuclicked')
        .html("");
}else{
    // First click
    $(this)
        .addClass('menuclicked');
        .html($('#hidediv').html());
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you're looking for:

```
$('.menuitem').click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $('div.hidediv').toggle(200);
});
```

Let me know if it is missing a feature.

http://jsfiddle.net/citizenconn/2bCdR/

Comment: Works but the problem that other divs with the class hidediv appears, it should only be the child of the .menuitem that is clicked

Comment: There is also a problem when the hidediv is clicked it hides, which it should not do only if the .menuitem is clicked

Comment: Your HTML structure is confusing, so each .menuItem should have a hidediv child?

Comment: See my answer, I address this issue. Its because your selector for the .click event is being used as a wrapper class for all of your checkboxes, causing the event to be bound to all your checkboxes.

Comment: When the .menuitem is clicked the checkbox should be checked and if the .menuitem is clicked again the .menuitem checkbox should be unchecked